# Comment « voire » a-t-il glissé sémantiquement à émettre un doute ?

Tags: étymologie

> #### [Étymologie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/voire#.C3.89tymologie)
>
> *(Siècle à préciser)* Du latin *[vera](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vera#la)*, pluriel neutre pris adverbialement de *[verus](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/verus#la)* (« [vrai](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vrai) », « [juste](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/juste) »).
>
> #### Adverbe [Les définitions :]
>
> 2. *([Vieilli](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Glossaire_grammatical#V))* *([Littéraire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Glossaire_grammatical#L))* Utilisé pour émettre un [doute](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/doute).

Ce glissement sémantique me déroute; il m'apparaît une volte-face, car le doute oppose la vérité.

Comment: C'est probablement un cas similaire à *certainement*, dont la fonction est aussi d'émettre un doute. Dans le cas où le vieil usage se voulait ironique on dirait maintenant *Mais certainement !* pour signifier son exact contraire. L'origine du sens qui subsiste de nos jours et qui permet de renchérir sur un point me semble un peu plus intrigante de par sa nature grammaticale assez unique. Ce sens de *voire x* est à rapprocher de *peut-être même x en vérité*.

Comment: Ou même "sans doute" qui signifie généralement "peut-être"

Comment: Le doute ne s'oppose pas au vrai, il hésite entre le *vrai* et le *faux*...

Answer (score 3):

[Voire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voire) au TLFi. Après une acception à peu près disparue (A) où le sens positif est entièrement conservé, nous avons une définition vieillie, mais encore en général comprise, dans laquelle l’ironie et le doute se présentent :

> *Vieilli, littér. ou p. plaisant.* [Empl. p. antiphr. pour nier qqc. ou exprimer un doute]
>   *Nous avions beau alléger notre défaite en y mettant de l'ironie, nous nous sentions cocus, certes, et pas contents. Pas contents? **Voire.** À l'occasion, nous y allions encore d'un beau discours* (Abellio, *Pacifiques,* 1946, p. 277).
>   *Mara: (...) voilà que tout est pour elle et rien pour moi. La Mère: Tu auras ta part. Mara:* ***Voire!*** (Claudel, *Annonce,* 1948, I, 2, p. 154).

Ce n’est pas sans rappeler un certain usage ironique d’autres mots à valeur de vérité :

> **Vraiment** charmant démolir ainsi l’héritage architectural de ce vieux quartier ! Un **véritable** tour-de-force ! Chapeau !

Bien sûr, *vraiment*, *véritable*, *vrai* et consorts sont encore compris positivement dans leur usage général non ironique. *Voire*, moins présent dans l’usage, n’est à peu près usité que dans sa valeur équivalent à *même*, souvent même en conjonction avec ce mot *(voire même)*, et dans une moindre proportion dans l’usage ironique cité ci-dessus.

En élaborant un peu, en lisant entre les lignes, on pourrait comprendre :

> — Je pourrais jongler avec six œufs sans les casser...
>   — **Voire !** <sub>*(Et si tu tentais d’être **réaliste** plutôt que de nous servir de telles bêtises ?)*</sub>

---

Je complète avec un rapprochement avec un autre mot rare, [chiche³, interj.](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/chiche), dont le sens peut être positif *(être chiche de → être capable de)*, et qui s’emploie lui aussi laconiquement, seul, avec une forte dose d’ironie.

Il permet de lancer un défi en prenant au mot une parole lancée, en supposant avec assez de certitude que son accomplissement n’aura jamais lieu :

> — Je pourrais jongler avec six œufs sans les casser...
>   — **Chiche !** <sub>*(Comprendre : Toi tu vas nous démontrer qu’on ne fait pas d’omelettes sans casser des œufs !)*</sub>